# TortoiseSVN: How do I export an entire file tree from a specific date

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have my project in Tortoise SVN repository.

I want to export the project to the disk, to the same state it was on a specific date.
I do not have a branch/tag for that date. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I suggest editing the title of this question to something similar to "How do I export files from a specific date?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  SVN will accept a date in lieu of a revision number, for example:

```
svn export -r {2009-02-17}
```

See [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) for info on date specifiers.

Comment: This is good info, I didn't know that. +1. But the caveat from my answer (3rd paragraph) applies here as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can export data from a certain *revision* only.

This is valid no matter whether you specify a revision number, or a date. (You can specify a date to find the nearest revision to a date, as described in Michael Hackner's answer.)

If you need to restore data because of a crash, this is reliable only if you always made full commits. It would be possible that only a certain directory or file was checked in. That wou td have created a new revision, that you get when querying for a date, but one that would not necessarily reflect the state of your working directory at the time.

Obviously, you can only recover data that was actually checked in to the repository.

Comment: And you can use filters in the log history to narrow down the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this with the -r{date}. For example to get the code as it was on 2009-12-20 (Dec 20, 2009),

`svn export -r{2009-12-20} svn://project/path/trunk export_directory`